# HDFS Java API checkPermissions

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I need to check if my code has write permission on directory in hdfs. So I want to use something like `hdfs.checkPermission(Path path)` but I only see `setPermission(Path p, FsPermission permission)` method in API. How can I do it?
Of course I can create a file inside the directory and catch an exception "Permission denied" if I have no write permission but it's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getPermission` is available with a `FileStatus` object

```
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration() )

val permissions = hdfs.getFileStatus(new Path("/user/cloudera/text.txt")).getPermission

org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission = rwxrwxrwx
```